# PonyORM retrieve object from class Entity problem

Tags: python, postgresql, ponyorm

Let's say I have these two classes:

```
class TeamMember(db.Entity):
    member_id= PrimaryKey(int, auto=True)
    name = Required(str)
    team = Required('Team')

class Team(db.Entity):
    team_id= PrimaryKey(int, auto=True)
    name = Required(str)
    team_members = Set(TeamMember)
```

I want to select all TeamMembers that are in specific team (ex. team_id==1). Query would look something like this (C1):

```
TeamMember.select(lambda member: member.team == 1)[:]
```

If I write it like that, I'm getting error below:

```
Incomparable types 'Team' and 'int' in expression: member.team == 1
```

On the other hand, I can write this and it will work (C2):

```
TeamMember.select(lambda member: member.team == Team[1])[:]
```

But, I don't wan't to write it like it, because I want to create generic function that will work for every Entity class:

```
def get_instances_from_db(classname, classname_var, var_value):
    """
    :param classname:  name of class
    :param classname_var: name of class variable to search by
    :param var_value: value of class variable
    :return:
    """
    return classname.select(lambda v: getattr(v, classname_var) == var_value)[:]
```

Above method will work for variable that's isn't relating to other class Entity like:

```
members = get_instances_from_db(TeamMember, "name", "some_team_member_name")
```

Finally, my question is: Is it possible to set query to search by integer, and not by Entity object. Or, is there way to use line 'C1'?

Hope I'm clear enough! :)

Comment: Could you have a check `isinstance(classname_var, db.Entity)` and then build a slightly different query which works on entities?

Comment: Good idea! Thank you, I will definitely try that.